# How to make Youtube embeded video responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

The example website: http://zh.gopro.com/

As can be seen, the header youtube video is responsive (resize automatically when window resizes), the `<iframe>` codes are below:

```
<iframe id="bluetube-player-1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="944" height="531" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/F1jpCBPiWS4?showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;modestbranding=0&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fzh.gopro.com" style="width: 1125px; height: 633px; left: 0px; top: -158.5px; position: relative;">

</iframe>
```

I found the `width`, `height` and `style` attributes are all be responsive in this page. But I didn't find how the author makes this (css or js?).. I tried to find jQuery method by using `bluetube` to search but still didn't understand how it works..

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: The video on your example website is actually not responsive, it doesn't resize properly according to your window. He is only using a media query to resize the video once the window is smaller than a certain width (most likely aimed for mobile).

Comment: @DarkAshelin Do you mean he uses `@media (min-width: xxx)` in css? If so, why does `width`, `height` and `style` attribute will be changed when video is resized...

Comment: I haven't looked into detail what code is used on your example website, but if you try resizing your window you will see that part of the video will be clipped if your window is too small. You won't be able to see what happens on the left and right corners. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: @DarkAshelin Actually that is exactly what I need..  If video is not clipped, there will be ugly black edging in the  top and the bottom of the Page..

Comment: Since you tagged this as Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed

Answer (score 4):

The video on your example website is actually not responsive, it doesn't resize properly according to your window (the sides simply get clipped). He is most likely just using a media query to resize the video once the window is smaller than a certain width (most likely aimed for mobile).

However, what you want to achieve is actually possible, if you use a container element which has an intrinsic aspect ratio, then absolute position the video within that.

### HTML

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
    <!-- The width and height here are ignored, and can actually be removed -->
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ygVQ8R-ZtZA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 ratio */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6fju59hp/)

Source and more information about responsive video embedding can be found [here](http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php).

Comment: Actually that is exactly what I need.. If video is not clipped, there will be ugly black edging in the top and the bottom of the Page while resizing the window....

Comment: Does the video which you are trying this with have black edges?